# Xpath query to find elements which contain a certain descendant

Tags: xpath

I'm using Html Agility Pack to run xpath queries on a web page.  I want to find the rows in a table which contain a certain interesting element.  In the example below, I want to fetch the second row.

```
<table name="important">
<tr>
  <td>Stuff I'm NOT interested in</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Stuff I'm interested in</td>
  <td><interestingtag/></td>
  <td>More stuff I'm interested in</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Stuff I'm NOT interested in</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Stuff I'm NOT interested in</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'm looking to do something like this:

```
//table[@name='important']/tr[has a descendant named interestingtag]
```

Except with valid xpath syntax.  ;-)

I suppose I could just find the interesting element itself and then work my way up the parent chain from the node that's returned, but it seemed like there ought to be a way to do this in one step and I'm just being dense.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

"has a descendant named interestintag" is spelled `.//interestintag` in XPath, so the expression you are looking for is:

```
//table[@name='important']/tr[.//interestingtag]
```

Comment: very interesting solution

Answer (score 30):

Actually, you need to look for a descendant, not a child:

```
//table[@name='important']/tr[descendant::interestingtag]
```

Comment: Excellent.  That's very helpful.  Sorry I can't accept two answers!

Comment: I always find it fun how many ways there are to get the desired result in XPath. I believe //table[@name='important']//interestingtag//ancestor::tr should work too I believe.

Comment: @Jeremy Stein: No problem, he beat me to it fair & square.  :-)

Comment: +1 for using the "descendant" axis. More readable than the ".//" shorthand, IMHO.

Comment: @Tomalak: you're too kind.  :-)  I find it more readable as well... too easy to misplace or not see the period, IMHO.

Comment: +1 from me too, I am used to the ".//" form, but I also do Perl for a living ;--) so "descendant::" is probably clearer.

Comment: I believe that the descendant axis is only valid in XSLT 3.0 though (at least that's the error that Saxon gives when I tried it out). So you might be stuck with .// if you're not on XSLT 3.0 yet.

Answer (score 13):

I know this isn't what the OP was asking, but if you wanted to find an element that had a descendant with a particular *attribute*, you could do something like this:

```
//table[@name='important']/tr[.//*[@attr='value']]
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it is a late answer but why not going the other way around. Finding all `<interestingtag/>` tags and then select the parent `<tr>` tag.

```
//interestingtag/ancestor::tr
```