# XPath in SelectNodes to choose all nodes where a particular grandchild node is present, regardless of value

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xsd

I have an XSD document, and I need to select all nodes that match a certain layout.

Here's a snippet of the XSD:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="MachineParameters">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="stMachineParameters"
         minOccurs="1"
         maxOccurs="1">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="CPSPEED"
                     minOccurs="1"
             maxOccurs="1">
                  <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>CPSPEEDDesc</xsd:documentation>
        <xsd:appinfo>false</xsd:appinfo>
          </xsd:annotation>
          <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base = "xsd:decimal">
                    </xsd:restriction>
                  </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>  
                <xsd:element name="STVARZPARAMS"
                     minOccurs="1"
                             maxOccurs="1">
                  <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                      <xsd:element name="VARIABLEZFASTVELOCITY">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                          <xsd:documentation>VARIABLEZFASTVELOCITYDesc</xsd:documentation>
                          <xsd:appinfo>false</xsd:appinfo>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                          <xsd:restriction base = "xsd:decimal">
                            <xsd:minInclusive value="0" />
                            <xsd:maxInclusive value="1" />
                          </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                      </xsd:element>
```

And so on.

I am trying to write some C# code to run through my entire document and return me a list of any element where an xsd:appinfo has been specified, regardless of value.

I've been struggling with this for a while and feel like I am close, but so far I haven't hit on the right Xpath query (I haven't used it before).

Here's the C#:

```
elementInfo = new Dictionary<string, DictionaryInfo>();

XmlNodeList nodeList;
XmlNode root = xmlDocSchema.DocumentElement;


try
{
    // the presence of an annotation/appinfo for the element is being used to identify it as a value element
    XmlNamespaceManager xmlNamespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocSchema.NameTable);
    xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    nodeList = root.SelectNodes("/*/element[/annotation/appinfo='false' or /annotation/appinfo='true']", xmlNamespaceManager);
}
catch (System.Xml.XPath.XPathException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Xpath exception: {0}", ex.Message));
    nodeList = null;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("General exception: {0}", ex.Message));
    nodeList = null;
}
```

Could someone suggest where I'm going wrong (and how to go right!)?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093904/xpath-query-to-find-elements-which-contain-a-certain-descendant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use

```
"//xsd:element[xsd:annotation/xsd:appinfo]"
```

as your xpath. There are a couple of changes to what you were using:

- `//element` is the syntax for selecting an element at any level in the document. `/*/element` selects only elements that are children of the root node.
- You need to use the namespace prefix on every element using that namespace in your XPath.
- There's no need to check the value of a predicate if you're not interested in it; just specifying an element name (or path) checks for existence.
- Starting a predicate with `/` is rarely what you want. It ignores the current context, and tries to match the predicate starting at the root of the document (in your case, the predicate `[/annotation/appinfo]` is only true if the root-node is an annotation element, with an appinfo child.)

Comment: Thanks.  That answered the question perfectly, with extra info to guide me in the future. I don't suppose you also know how I can access the parent nodes of elements once they have been put into the list by SelectNodes?

Comment: Sadly, I'm not really a c# guy, so I can't help you with its specific APIs; I'm sure if you open a new question about that, someone will be able to help out though.