# picking only the video with the lock sign or the membership only sign

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, webdriver-io

I am trying to run an end to end test using WebdriverIO, and the main test case is supposed to choose the video with the specific icon (in this case for members only), and I have the selector set up in a way to create an array of the videos while choosing the very first video, however this chooses any video and not the first of the membership only videos, **any tips on how to include the membership lock selector?**

**This is the HTML code for the individual video:**

```html
<div class="thumb vidItem" data-video-id="797127">
        <span class="thumb-inner-wrapper">
            <a href="/videos/797127/?">
                <img src="?" alt="?">
            </a>
        </span>
        <a class="thumb-link-wrapper js-rotate" href="?" title="?" data-video-preview="?">
        </a>
        <div class="vidItemAction no-popup">
    <a href="?" class="add-to-list favorite" data-list-id="f_1_797127" data-remove="Remove from Favorites" data-add="Add to Favorites" title="Add to Favorites"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a>
<a href="/ajax-add-watchLater/?contentType=1&amp;contentId=797127" class="add-to-list watchLater" data-list-id="w_1_797127" data-remove="Remove from Watch Later" data-add="Add to Watch Later" title="Add to Watch Later"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></a>
<span class="user-not-logged"> You must be <a href="?" data-js="loginpopup" title="Login">logged in</a>.</span>

</div>
<span class="video-in-list"> Added to Playlist </span>

        
        <div class="fs11 viddata flr time-label-wrapper">
            
            <span class="membership-block member-only"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>

            <span class="text-active bold">1080p</span>
            <span>
                01:00
            </span>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="thumb-comment-area-wrapper">
            
        </div>
        
            <div class="videoRating"><div class="progress-small js-rating-title green" title="98%">
    <div class="inl-block rating js-rating-title js-rating-text-percent">98<span>%</span></div>
</div>
</div>
```

**and this is the code that I have so far that creates an array and chooses the first video:**

```
  const video = await $$('a.thumb-link-wrapper.js-rotate')[0];
await video.click();
```

Comment: You would have to start by selecting the wrapping container div, instead of the link element directly - only if that container div contains a `.member-only` element, it is the one you want. Webdriver does not appear to support a `:has` selector (https://webdriver.io/docs/selectors), but it supports XPath, so you should be able to use something along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1093904/1427878

Comment: and is there no way to do it through classic css selectors, cause in this case the main container is thumb vidItem, but I'm not sure how to exactly include the descendant

Comment: You would need something like the `:has` selector to begin with, which this library does not appear to understand. (It's a CSS Selectors Level 4 feature, which doesn't even have wide support in actual browsers yet, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#browser_compatibility)