# how to fetch the dividend % on several stock exchanges (formula works but not for all)

Tags: xml, google-sheets, finance, yahoo

The formula below works, but not always. It looks to be dependent of the stock exchange where it is traded on.

```
=IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/", index(A2)),"/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]")
```

Can someone help me with the formula of ticker `CPINV.BR`? In Yahoo Finance, it can be found [here](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/CPINV.BR?p=CPINV.BR&.tsrc=fin-srch). I want to obtain the 'Forward Dividend & Yield' of 7.17%. How to I do this?

FYI, below an example of a Google Sheets where the formula above works for some tickers and not for others. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VUgq63x3n5UxvWUiyuW7sG8iM6dZ7i3tZSLN3Tfq2AI/edit?usp=sharing

Can also someone link the description on how the table in Yahoo are built up? This is so useful since I want to be able to filter on several parameters, but can't determine the 'table and row' logic on Yahoo Finance.

Comment: The XPATH you are using is will not work on all exchanges.  The results are in a table with tbody.  So just look for the tbody because the number of advertisements on the results are going to be different.  The data is starting 6 rows after tbody starting in column 2 (index 1).

Comment: Thx for the answer, I tried to adapt, but in vain. Can You adapt 1 ticker of the Linked Google Sheets, then I will get the hang of it and see how to adapt. I inspected the HTML but am unsuccessfull in definein 'column 2 and especially index1 for the tickers where the code does not work.

Comment: Use DESCENDANT and look for tbody.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093904/xpath-query-to-find-elements-which-contain-a-certain-descendant

Answer (score 0):

Here is code using Powershell with HTMLAgilityPack.  I used Descendants

```
#needed to upgrade from PS 5 to PS 7
Add-Type -path "$env:UserProfile\Desktop\PowerShell\htmlagilitypack\lib\NetCore45\htmlagilitypack.dll"

$URI = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/CPINV.BR?p=CPINV.BR&.tsrc=fin-srch'
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Takes an HTML input and converts it to an HTMLAgilityPack htmlNode object that can be navigated using Linq
.DESCRIPTION
    Long description
.EXAMPLE
    PS C:\> <example usage>
    Explanation of what the example does
.INPUTS
    [String[]]
    [System.IO.FileInfo[]]
.OUTPUTS
    [HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument]
    [HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode]
.NOTES
    General notes
#>
function ConvertFrom-Html {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="String")]
    param (
        #The HTML text to parse. Accepts multiple separate documents as an array. This also accepts pipeline from Invoke-WebRequest
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="String",Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName,Position=0)]
        [String[]]$Content,

        #The URI or URIs from which to retrieve content. This may be faster than using Invoke-WebRequest but is less flexible in the method of retrieval (for instance, no POST)
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="URI",Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [System.URI[]]$URI,

        #Path to file or files containing HTML content to convert. This accepts pipeline from Get-Childitem or Get-Item
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Path",Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [System.IO.FileInfo[]]$Path,

        #Do not return the Linq documentnode, instead return the HTMLDocument object. This is useful if you want to do XPath queries instead of Linq queries
        [switch]$Raw

    )

    begin {
    }

    process {
        #Find the type of input and bind it to inputObject
        $inputObject = $null
        foreach ($contentType in "Content","URI","Path") {
            if ((Get-Variable -erroraction SilentlyContinue $contentType).value) {
                $inputObject = (Get-Variable $contentType).value
                break
            }
        }
        if (-not $inputObject) {write-error "Input Object Type Not Identified. If you see this then ConvertFrom-HTML needs better input validation"}

        #Unwrap any arrays. This allows us to accept both pipeline and parameter input
        $inputObject | ForEach-Object {
            $inputItem = $PSItem
            $htmlDoc = new-object HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument

            #Process all object types into a common HTML document format
            switch ($inputItem.GetType().FullName) {
                "System.String" {
                    $htmlDoc.LoadHtml($inputItem)
                }
                "System.Uri" {
                    $htmlDoc = (new-object HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb).Load($inputItem)
                }
                "System.IO.FileInfo" {
                    $htmlDoc.Load($inputItem)
                }
                Default {
                    write-error "Object Type not supported or implemented. If you see this error then ConvertFrom-HTML has improper input validation"
                    continue
                }
            }
            if ($inputItem) {
                if ($Raw) {
                    $htmlDoc
                } else {
                    $htmlDoc.DocumentNode
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$res = $wc.DownloadString($URI)
$html = ConvertFrom-Html -Content $res
$tbody = $html.Descendants('tbody')
```

Look like there is two Results

```
Attributes           : {}
ChildNodes           : {tr, tr, tr, tr...}
Closed               : True
ClosingAttributes    : {}
EndNode              : HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
FirstChild           : HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
HasAttributes        : False
HasChildNodes        : True
HasClosingAttributes : False
Id                   :
InnerHtml            : <tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s) Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td class="C($primaryColor)
                       W(51%)"><span>Previous Close</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)"
                       data-test="PREV_CLOSE-value">13.50</td></tr><tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s)
                       Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>Open</span></td><td
                       class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)" data-test="OPEN-value">13.50</td></tr><tr class="Bxz(bb)
                       Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s) Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td class="C($primaryColor)
                       W(51%)"><span>Bid</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)" data-test="BID-value">0.00 x
                       0</td></tr><tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s) Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td
                       class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>Ask</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)"
                       data-test="ASK-value">0.00 x 0</td></tr><tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s)
                       Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>Day&#x27;s
                       Range</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)" data-test="DAYS_RANGE-value">13.30 -
                       13.68</td></tr><tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s) Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td
                       class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>52 Week Range</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600)
                       Lh(14px)" data-test="FIFTY_TWO_WK_RANGE-value">10.70 - 16.52</td></tr><tr class="Bxz(bb)
                       Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s) Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td class="C($primaryColor)
                       W(51%)"><span>Volume</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)"
                       data-test="TD_VOLUME-value"><fin-streamer data-symbol="CPINV.BR"
                       data-field="regularMarketVolume" data-trend="none" data-pricehint="2" data-dfield="longFmt"
                       value="36,813" active="">36,813</fin-streamer></td></tr><tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s)
                       Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) Bdbw(0)! "><td class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>Avg.
                       Volume</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)"
                       data-test="AVERAGE_VOLUME_3MONTH-value">35,029</td></tr>
InnerText            : Previous Close13.50Open13.50Bid0.00 x 0Ask0.00 x 0Day&#x27;s Range13.30 - 13.6852 Week
                       Range10.70 - 16.52Volume36,813Avg. Volume35,029
LastChild            : HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
Line                 : 26
LinePosition         : 9697
InnerStartIndex      : 100941
OuterStartIndex      : 100934
InnerLength          : 1894
OuterLength          : 1909
Name                 : tbody
NextSibling          :
NodeType             : Element
OriginalName         : tbody
OuterHtml            : <tbody><tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s) Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td
                       class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>Previous Close</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600)
                       Lh(14px)" data-test="PREV_CLOSE-value">13.50</td></tr><tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s)
                       Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>Open</span></td><td
                       class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)" data-test="OPEN-value">13.50</td></tr><tr class="Bxz(bb)
                       Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s) Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td class="C($primaryColor)
                       W(51%)"><span>Bid</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)" data-test="BID-value">0.00 x
                       0</td></tr><tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s) Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td
                       class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>Ask</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)"
                       data-test="ASK-value">0.00 x 0</td></tr><tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s)
                       Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>Day&#x27;s
                       Range</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)" data-test="DAYS_RANGE-value">13.30 -
                       13.68</td></tr><tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s) Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td
                       class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>52 Week Range</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600)
                       Lh(14px)" data-test="FIFTY_TWO_WK_RANGE-value">10.70 - 16.52</td></tr><tr class="Bxz(bb)
                       Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s) Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td class="C($primaryColor)
                       W(51%)"><span>Volume</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)"
                       data-test="TD_VOLUME-value"><fin-streamer data-symbol="CPINV.BR"
                       data-field="regularMarketVolume" data-trend="none" data-pricehint="2" data-dfield="longFmt"
                       value="36,813" active="">36,813</fin-streamer></td></tr><tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s)
                       Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) Bdbw(0)! "><td class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>Avg.
                       Volume</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)"
                       data-test="AVERAGE_VOLUME_3MONTH-value">35,029</td></tr></tbody>
OwnerDocument        : HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
ParentNode           : HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
PreviousSibling      :
StreamPosition       : 100934
XPath                : /html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/di
                       v[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]
Depth                : 0

Attributes           : {}
ChildNodes           : {tr, tr, tr, tr...}
Closed               : True
ClosingAttributes    : {}
EndNode              : HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
FirstChild           : HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
HasAttributes        : False
HasChildNodes        : True
HasClosingAttributes : False
Id                   :
InnerHtml            : <tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s) Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td class="C($primaryColor)
                       W(51%)"><span>Market Cap</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)"
                       data-test="MARKET_CAP-value">499.35M</td></tr><tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s)
                       Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>Beta (5Y
                       Monthly)</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)"
                       data-test="BETA_5Y-value">0.22</td></tr><tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s)
                       Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>PE Ratio
                       (TTM)</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)"
                       data-test="PE_RATIO-value">23.17</td></tr><tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s)
                       Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>EPS
                       (TTM)</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)"
                       data-test="EPS_RATIO-value">0.58</td></tr><tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s)
                       Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>Earnings
                       Date</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)" data-test="EARNINGS_DATE-value"><span>Mar
                       06, 2024</span> - <span>Mar 11, 2024</span></td></tr><tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s)
                       Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>Forward Dividend &amp;
                       Yield</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)" data-test="DIVIDEND_AND_YIELD-value">0.94
                       (6.96%)</td></tr><tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s) Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td
                       class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>Ex-Dividend Date</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600)
                       Lh(14px)" data-test="EX_DIVIDEND_DATE-value"><span>May 31, 2023</span></td></tr><tr
                       class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s) Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) Bdbw(0)! "><td
                       class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>1y Target Est</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600)
                       Lh(14px)" data-test="ONE_YEAR_TARGET_PRICE-value">15.20</td></tr>
InnerText            : Market Cap499.35MBeta (5Y Monthly)0.22PE Ratio (TTM)23.17EPS (TTM)0.58Earnings DateMar 06, 2024
                       - Mar 11, 2024Forward Dividend &amp; Yield0.94 (6.96%)Ex-Dividend DateMay 31, 20231y Target
                       Est15.20
LastChild            : HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
Line                 : 26
LinePosition         : 11868
InnerStartIndex      : 103112
OuterStartIndex      : 103105
InnerLength          : 1850
OuterLength          : 1865
Name                 : tbody
NextSibling          :
NodeType             : Element
OriginalName         : tbody
OuterHtml            : <tbody><tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s) Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td
                       class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>Market Cap</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600)
                       Lh(14px)" data-test="MARKET_CAP-value">499.35M</td></tr><tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s)
                       Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>Beta (5Y
                       Monthly)</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)"
                       data-test="BETA_5Y-value">0.22</td></tr><tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s)
                       Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>PE Ratio
                       (TTM)</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)"
                       data-test="PE_RATIO-value">23.17</td></tr><tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s)
                       Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>EPS
                       (TTM)</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)"
                       data-test="EPS_RATIO-value">0.58</td></tr><tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s)
                       Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>Earnings
                       Date</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)" data-test="EARNINGS_DATE-value"><span>Mar
                       06, 2024</span> - <span>Mar 11, 2024</span></td></tr><tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s)
                       Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>Forward Dividend &amp;
                       Yield</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)" data-test="DIVIDEND_AND_YIELD-value">0.94
                       (6.96%)</td></tr><tr class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s) Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) "><td
                       class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>Ex-Dividend Date</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600)
                       Lh(14px)" data-test="EX_DIVIDEND_DATE-value"><span>May 31, 2023</span></td></tr><tr
                       class="Bxz(bb) Bdbw(1px) Bdbs(s) Bdc($seperatorColor) H(36px) Bdbw(0)! "><td
                       class="C($primaryColor) W(51%)"><span>1y Target Est</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600)
                       Lh(14px)" data-test="ONE_YEAR_TARGET_PRICE-value">15.20</td></tr></tbody>
OwnerDocument        : HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
ParentNode           : HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
PreviousSibling      :
StreamPosition       : 103105
XPath                : /html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/di
                       v[1]/div[2]/div[2]/table[1]/tbody[1]
Depth                : 0
```